# Why doesn't Tony Stark get hurt by the inside of his Iron Man suit?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe Tony Stark repeatedly falls from a great height. Tony survives! Tony gets hit by a rocket. Tony survives! But that is from the outside.

But how does the Iron Man suit protect him from the inside?

We all saw that the suit has no inner cushion sort of thing so how does he not get hurt?

Comment: Another thing is how he's not vaporised by his absurd power source. BTW no cushioning, not even full liquid submersion would make him survive some of those things.

Comment: I think this is just over-analysing. After all, it's a movie about a guy that built a suit that flies, in a cave, almost entirely by himself... To watch any super hero movies you need quite some suspension of disbelief.

Comment: something, something.... midichlorians.

Comment: definition of **Armor**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Movie/Comic Physics.

No amount of padding can overcome G-forces. Only extreme and brutal training, like the one astronauts go through. The reason this happens is because they affect your inner organs and blood. From [here](https://gearpatrol.com/2017/10/04/hook-maneuver-agsm-tutorial/):

> Symptoms of encountering g’s include “graying out,” or passing out, due to blood flowing out of your brain and into your lower extremities.

So how does Tony not pass out from massive G's? How does he crash but remain fine inside the suit? **Movie physics (derived from comic physics).** If you instantly stop from going at 200km/h, you die, your body can't handle the acceleration change. This kind of physics just makes things more entertaining for us, viewers.

**We can basically assume that as long as the suit remains, Tony isn't harmed.**

Comment: *velocity change :p

Comment: Actually acceleration change is ok here.

Answer (score 3):

## Unclear.

There is another post similar to this over on SFF.SE.

> The movie armor that swoops in behind Tony to save him from falling did seem to be rather bulky and I would like to think in a perfect world there is a mixture of armor, padding, force-fields, hyper-oxygenation and fitness keeping Tony from being crushed by the g-forces of those amazingly tight turns and incredible amounts of physical abuse he suffers during the movie.[image: Iron Man Suit]
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Why is Tony Stark in the Iron Man suit unaffected by G-forces, inertia and blunt force trauma? - SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/why-is-tony-stark-in-the-iron-man-suit-unaffected-by-g-forces-inertia-and-blunt)</sub>

We can't know for sure but it's possible that there is some kind of padding inside Tony's suit.